# Call method from my class throws an error

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I want access my method that is in my class after i upload some file but i am getting error that function is not defined.

my html:

```
<input type="file" id="myFiles">
```

my javascript:

```
class fileRead{
constructor(){
  this.myInput = document.getElementById("myFiles");
}

addListener = () =>{
    this.myInput.addEventListener('change', function(){
        this.call(this);
    })
}

call = (fileData) =>{
  console.log(fileData);
   }
}
 const a = new fileRead();
 a.addListener();
```

Comment: Partially the problem is [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484) the biggest problem here is that `function(){ this.call(this); })` expects `this` to have *two different values*. One time it must be a `fileReadt` object, in order to do `.call` on it, another time it has to be the element in which is passed into that call. You are better off binding that directly `this.myInput.addEventListener('change', this.call)` or alternatively using an arrow function and the event parameter `e => this.call(e.target)`

Comment: nice e => this.call(e.target) its working thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't** need `=>` arrow notation to define class methods.
You **do** need `=>` notation when defining addEventListeners, this helps all your code remain in the same scope.

In the below example, the keyword `this` will always refer to the `fileRead` class instance. If you need to know who exactly triggered the event, you can use the event target.

```
class fileRead {
    constructor(){
        this.myInput = document.getElementById("myFiles");
    }

    addListener(){
        this.myInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            this.call(event);
        })
    }

   call(event){
        // you can use event.target to know what form field changed
        // or you can just access this.myInput to know the form field content
        console.log(event.target.fileData);
        console.log(this.myInput.fileData);
   }
}

 const a = new fileRead();
 a.addListener();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you used an arrow function in a class property your function `addListener` is only defined on the initialization by the constructor and not in the prototype.

You could try to declare your class function as follows:

> ```
> addListener () {
>     this.myInput.addEventListener('change', function(){
>         this.call(this);
>     })
> }
> ```

Source: https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1